# output layer is a function instead of a layer

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am getting this error but this is working for other people.

```
TypeError: output_layer must be a Layer, received: <class ‘function’> 

 output_layer = lambda x: tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(x, 
                                                            target_vocab_size, None, scope=decoding_scope)
```

If I try to pass something in, this I get a different error about a non-floating point number

```
output_fn = (output_layer(dec_input))

TypeError: Cannot create initializer for non-floating point type.
```

Which I think might be related this part but I'm not sure what is wrong with it because if I keep the type as int32 then the tests pass but if I change it to float32 then the test don't pass.

```
   start_tokens = tf.tile(tf.constant([start_of_sequence_id], dtype=tf.int32),[batch_size])
    inference_helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.GreedyEmbeddingHelper(dec_embeddings, 
                                                                start_tokens = start_tokens,
                                                                end_token=end_of_sequence_id)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal but fully executable code block and I'll have a look